# core-plot bar chart bound to a NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, core-plot, nsarraycontroller

I'm trying to design a bar graph that will get its data from a NSArrayController which itself is bound to another data source.

What's the correct approach here?

- My Graph controller is a subclass of NSArrayController
- In controller's awakeFromNib, I draw the graph and setup the bindings:

-(void)awakeFromNib {

[super awakeFromNib];

```
// Add plot space for horizontal bar charts
CPTXYPlotSpace *barPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
barPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-20.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(200.0f)];
barPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-7.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(15.0f)];
[graph addPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];
//[barPlotSpace release];

// First bar plot
CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [[CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor darkGrayColor] horizontalBars:YES] retain];
barPlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromFloat(20.0f);
barPlot.dataSource = self;
barPlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.25f);
barPlot.identifier = barPlot1;
barPlot.plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(7.0)];
barPlot.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;
[graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];

/*
// Second bar plot
barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:YES];
barPlot.dataSource = self;
barPlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromFloat(20.0f);
barPlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.25f);
barPlot.cornerRadius = 2.0;
barPlot.identifier = barPlot2;
barPlot.plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(7.0)];
barPlot.delegate = self;
[graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];  
 */

[barPlot bind:CPTBarPlotBindingBarLocations
                toObject:self withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:nil];  }
```

is this the correct way to do this?

My arrangedObjects is a set of Managed objects that have a name and a time field that I need to graph.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bindings, don't set the datasource. Don't forget to bind a field to `CPTBarPlotBindingBarTips`, too.

The CPTTestApp example app demonstrates binding a scatter plot to an array controller. The process for a bar plot is same except the binding constants have different names.

Comment: I looked at the sample app for scatter plot, however, I'm not sure how I should bind arrangedObjects (from NSArrayController) to the graph?  What fields should my arrangedObjects have? (x,y?) and what are the binding constants on the graph side?

Comment: The bindings constants are `CPTBarPlotBindingBarLocations` and `CPTBarPlotBindingBarTips`. You control the names within `arrangedObjects`. You can see this in CPTTestApp by selecting the "XY Values Controller" in Interface Builder and opening the Attributes Inspector pane on the right side.

Comment: Understood, but what exactly does _CPTBarPlotBindingBarLocations_ and *CPTBarPlotBindingBarTips* mean?  Let's say on my X-Axis I have a bunch of companies, with Y-Axis is the number of employees in each company.  My arrangedObjects is an array of dictionaries with .name = company name .employees = num of employees.  How would I setup the binding?

Comment: The location and tip values both have to be numbers--there's no built-in support for categorical data yet. My suggestion would be to bind only the tip values. The plot will then use a simple index for the locations (0, 1, 2, etc.). You can use an axis delegate to covert the location to the name of the company when making labels.

Comment: @Eric You said not to set the dataSource for bindings but the current CPTTestApp is using the dataSource methods for the CPTScatterPlot which is using bindings.  Is the settings a dataSource required to get bindings to work with a bart plot?

Comment: @dbainbridge *CPTTestApp* uses bindings for one of the scatter plots and a datasource for the other. This demonstrates how you can mix and match as needed. All plot types work the same way.